# Explode a table with a monthly increment in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a sample table:

| id | start_dt | end_dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 06/07/2021 | 30/09/2021 |

I would like to get the following output

| id | start_dt | end_dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 06/07/2021 | 31/07/2021 |
| 100 | 01/08/2021 | 30/08/2021 |
| 100 | 01/09/2021 | 30/09/2021 |

I have tried using GENERATE_SERIES() in Amazon Redshift, but that does not give the required result.

The existing table is quite large so I could use temp tables then join back to another table at a later stage.

I have trawled through other posts, but other proposed solutions isn't quite giving the desired results / don't work at all on Amazon Redshift. Any help in solving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional method would be:

- Create a `Calendar` table that contains one row per month, with start_date and end_date columns
- Join your table to the `Calendar` table, where `table.start_dt <= calendar.end_dt AND table.end_dt >= calendar.start_dt`
- The two columns would be:

  - `GREATEST(table.start_dt, calendar.start_dt)`
  - `LEAST(table.end_dt, calendar.end_dt)`

Comment: thank you John. I did a cross join however I am only getting matches for the full months, and where the month is short the full number of days for the month, I don't get a row. any suggestions on this ?

Comment: Using your above example, are you saying that the first row needs to show `06/07/2021` instead of the start of the month? Keep the joins the same, but for that column use `GREATEST(table.start_dt, calendar.start_dt)` and the other column would be `LEAST(table.end_dt, calendar.end_dt)`.

Comment: yeah for the first row the start should show 06/07/2021. For the last it could also show 29/09/2021 if the end date was 29/09/2021

Comment: all is working now, thank you for your help!